# Batch Convert .xls files and add background image | header/footer

Tags: background, xls

i am running latest arch linux and tried to batch convert xls files to pdf which workes fine with the following command:

```
lowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.xls
```

But those xls files require an additional background image / header / footer stuff with the company information. Dont ask why they have done it that way ;). I just need to figure out a pretty and fast solution for this.

Any help is very appreciated.

Regards and thanks in advance
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a simple and fast solution myself. Found a tool in the AUR of arch called pdftk which works as follows:

```
pdftk fg.pdf background bg.pdf output new.pdf
```

i just wrote a simple php script to execute it in a loop.
Done, thanks anyway.